# why is this code not running on vscode but its running on online compilers

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

code running on online compilers but not on vscode
using basic extension c/c++ compiler by microscoft

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ int c;
    printf("enter a value:");
c = getchar();
printf("\nyou entered:");
putchar(c);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you have posted. Can you explain what you mean by "does not run"?

Comment: its shows running but after that nothing happens... its doesnt ask for input as it does in online compilers. so i have to myself end the code